# Form Validation in php || No response for the request

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have created a html page with 4 inputs:Name,email,gender,comment and one submit button and jquery library. I have linked this page with a CSS page(style.css),one javascript file(script.js),one php page(validation.php). I have attached my code. However when I am clicking on my submit button I am not getting any response. Can someone please assist what is wrong in my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
  
  //  validation based on Regular expression (10 chars max, alpha and numeric allowed)
  // Name can't be blank
  $('#name2').on('input', function() {
   var input=$(this);
   var is_name=input.val();
   if(is_name){
    input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
   else{
    input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
   });
   
  // Email must be an email 
  $('#email2').on('input', function() {
   var input=$(this);
   var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
   var is_email=re.test(input.val());
   
   if(is_email){
    input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
   }
   else{
    input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });
  
  // Message can't be blank
  $('#comm').keyup(function(event) {
   var input=$(this);
   var message=$(this).val();
   console.log(message);
   
   if(message){
    input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
   else{
    input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    } 
  });

  //Check if gender is empty
  $('#gn').on('input', function() {
   var input=$(this);
   var is_gender=input.val();
   if(is_gender){
    input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
   else{
    input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });
  
  
  //  JQUERY MODAL WINDOW
  
  $.post( "validation.php", { 
  name: $("#name2").val(),
  email: $("#email2").val(),
  gender: $("#gn").val(),
  comment: $("#comm").val(),
  formHasbeenPosted: $("#yes").val()
  
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
   $("#result").html(data);
    });
  
  
  return false;
  
        });
})
```

```css
.maindiv{
margin:0 auto;
width:980px;
height:500px;
background:#fff;
padding-top:20px;
font-size:14px
}

.form_div{
width:70%;
float:left
}

form{
width:440px;
border:1px dashed #ccc;
padding:10px 30px 40px;
background-color:#f0f8ff;
font-family:'Droid Serif',serif
}
img
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 float: right;"
}
textarea{
width:250px;
height:60px;
border-radius:1px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
margin-top:10px;
padding:5px;
border:none
}
.input{
width:250px;
height:15px;
border-radius:1px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
margin-top:10px;
padding:5px;
border:none;
margin-bottom:20px
}
.button{
color:#fff;
border-radius:3px;
background:#1F8DD6;
padding:5px;
margin-top:40px;
border:none;
width:100px;
height:30px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
font-size:16px;
position:center
}
.error{
color:red
}
.error_show{
 color: red;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
input.invalid, textarea.invalid{
 border: 2px solid red;
}

input.valid, textarea.valid{
 border: 2px solid green;
}
.radio{
width:15px;
height:15px;
border-radius:1px;
margin-top:10px;
padding:5px;
border:none;
margin-bottom:20px
}
.formget{
float:right;
margin-top:85px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="form_div">
</div>
<form id="myForm">
<h2>Form</h2>
<img src="C:\wamp64\www\FormValidation\onelife.png" alt="Logo"><br>
<span class="error">* required field.</span><br>
Name:
<input class="input" id="name2" name="name" type="text" value="">
<span class="error">*</span> </br>
E-mail:
<input class="input" id="email2" name="email" type="text" value="">
<span class="error">*valid email address is required </span></br>
Gender:
<input class="radio" id="gn" name="gender" type="radio" value="female">Female
<input class="radio" id="gn" name="gender" type="radio" value="male">Male
<span class="error">*Please select a gender</span></br>
Comment:
<textarea cols="40" id="comm" name="comment" rows="5">
</textarea><br/>
<input class="submit" id="mybutton" type="button" value="Submit"><br/>
<div id="result"></div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
Validation.php

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
<?php
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";
$genderError ="";


if(isset($_POST['formHasbeenPosted'])){
 if (empty($_POST["name2"])) {
  $nameError = "Name is required";
 } else {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name2"]);

 // check name for alphanumeric values
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$name)) { 
  $nameError = "Only alphanumeric values allowed";
 }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["email2"])) {
  $emailError = "Email is required";
 } else {
  $email = test_input($_POST["email2"]);

 // check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
 if (!preg_match("/([w-]+@[w-]+.[w-]+)/",$email)) {
  $emailError = "Invalid email format";
 }
 }
 //Check if comment is empty
 if (empty($_POST["comm"])) {
  $comment = "";
  } else {
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comm"]);
 }

 //Check if gender is empty
 if (empty($_POST["gn"])) {
  $genderError = "Gender is required";
 } else {
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gn"]);
 }
}

function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use your browsers debug (F12) options this will get you a lot further ...

Comment: what does the network panel in the browser dev tools say is happening?

Comment: @Antony i tried to do that but i am understanding what is wrong. validation page is working fine but in response i have nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to echo something on validation.php, because from what I can see, nothing there is printed.
try this code

```
if(isset($_POST['formHasbeenPosted'])){
    if (empty($_POST["name2"])) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
        echo $nameError;
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name2"]);

    // check name for alphanumeric values
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$name)) { 
        $nameError = "Only alphanumeric values allowed";
        echo $nameError ;
    }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email2"])) {
        $emailError = "Email is required";
        echo $emailError ;
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email2"]);

    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
    if (!preg_match("/([w-]+@[w-]+.[w-]+)/",$email)) {
        $emailError = "Invalid email format";
        echo $emailError ;
    }
    }
    //Check if comment is empty
    if (empty($_POST["comm"])) {
        $comment = "";
        } else {
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comm"]);
    }

    //Check if gender is empty
    if (empty($_POST["gn"])) {
        $genderError = "Gender is required";
        echo $genderError ;
    } else {
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gn"]);
    }
if($nameError == "" && $emailError == "" && $genderError == ""){
    echo "Data is valid, you can process";
}
}
```

Comment: that's not the issue. I removed it still its not working. the problem is in my script. the script is directly returning false. I am not sure but there is some problem with click event in my script.

Comment: I updated my code, try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: glad it helped you out :) happy coding